# NAudio file saved in wave prepends added padding to the file

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, naudio, naudio-framework

I have code like so :

```
        mp3File = new Mp3FileReader("someMP3Files.mp3");
        WaveChannel32 inputStream = new WaveChannel32(mp3File);
        streamProcessor = new WaveStreamProcessor(inputStream);
        CreateWaveFile("test.wav", inputStream);
```

so basically it takes the mp3 and converts it to a wave file called test. Looking at the converted file, I see this using audacity.

Note the highlighted area why does it give the blank space and does not duplicate exactly as it is?

[image: Check the yellow section highlighted]

Any ideas?

My create wave method:

```
    public static void CreateWaveFile(string filename, WaveStream stream)
    {
        using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(filename, stream.WaveFormat))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
            while (true)
            {
                int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                    break;
                writer.WriteData(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
```

Clarification, the padding is actually added when the Mp3FileReader is created.

Comment: It is actually happening when the mp3 file is instantiated. the padding is added then and there.

Comment: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/audio_tracks.html#Arrows_at_the_start_of_the_track

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't get what you were referring to by the reference.

Comment: Top image appears to be a single t(mono?) rack, whereas the bottom one is a (stereo?) pair of tracks.   Is that just how Audacity shows it?   I wonder if there is some extra configuration you need to provide to NAudio to tell it the output format you want?

Comment: @Neil no both are stereo, I just did not post the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
MemoryStream mp3Buffered = new MemoryStream();
using (var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        mp3Buffered.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}

mp3Buffered.Position = 0;
using (var mp3Stream = new Mp3FileReader(mp3Buffered))
{    
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile("file.wav", mp3Stream);
}
```

I wasn't too sure what you meant by that question, however I tried my best and researched so this is what I found. And I also think padding is automatically added when those files are converted.

Note: Please don't bash me if I'm wrong in the comments, check my profile later and you'll see why. :)

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I will do some check in the code and see where. Marking your answer as useful. I see a good future :)

Comment: Does this actually fix the problem?   It just looks like you are reading the whole file into a memory stream, and then calling the same (set of) functions.

Comment: Did this help you by the way? I hope it did :)

Comment: Also, @Neil, I was basically doing just that, but it is much more flexible to ride in into a memory stream and then call the same set of functions, as I would take that approach to it. I tested out the code, it worked for me.

Comment: I don't understand why it's 'more flexible'.  Does this actually solve the problem?   Streams are generally a better solution because they don't use up lots of memory with large files.